# json Array PUSH

Tags: javascript, json

I have a `JSON` variable like this.

```
{
  "name": "test name",
  "place": "test place",
  "participants": {
    "one": {
      "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
      "name": "name 1"
    },
    "two": {
      "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
      "name": "name 2"
    }
  },
  "lat_long": "0.0,0.0"
}
```

How can i add following data to the `particpants` key of the above variable using javascript

```
"theree": {
  "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
  "name": "name 3"
}
```

so that my new `JSON` variable looks like this

```
{
  "name": "test name",
  "place": "test place",
  "participants": {
    "one": {
      "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
      "name": "name 1"
    },
    "two": {
      "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
      "name": "name"
    },
    "theree": {
      "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
      "name": "name 3"
    }
  },
  "lat_long": "0.0,0.0"
}
```

And how to identify JSON object and JSON array ?

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It's rather about how to process arrays/objects in JavaScript. *How* you obtained the data (e.g. via JSON) is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: This also has nothing to do with arrays as there are no arrays and no push method involved at all.  This question was extremely UNCLEAR what you wanted to do.  Good for Jyoti that they guessed appropriately, but it is frustrating to see such an unclear question, spend a bunch of time on it, offer three different possible solutions (based on different possible interpretations of what your question meant) including answering several of your questions and showing you several different things and then see your vote elsewhere.  Oh well, your choice I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   var newdata = {"three": {
       "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
       "name": "name 3"
       }
    };

   var newKey = Object.keys(newdata);
   data.participants[newKey[0]] = newdata[newKey[0]];

   console.log(data);
```

Your data may be :

```
 1.  var newdata = {"five": {
       "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
       "name": "name 3"
       }
    };

 2.  var newdata = {"four": {
       "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
       "name": "name 3"
       }
    };
```

It doesnot dependent on key.

Comment: @NikhilM - Keep in mind, this solution won't work with IE8 or earlier as `Object.keys()` doesn't exist in those browsers without adding your own compatibility layer.

Answer (score 4):

It is not fully clear exactly what you're asking since you don't show actual legal javascript, just data fragments.  So, I've offered 3 guesses as to what you might be asking:

If your initial data was named `data` like this:

```
var data = {
  "name": "test name",
  "place": "test place",
  "participants": {
    "one": {
      "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
      "name": "name 1"
    },
    "two": {
      "lat_long": "0.0,0.0",
      "name": "name 2"
    }
  },
  "lat_long": "0.0,0.0"
};
```

Then, you could add the `theree` property like this:

```
data.participants.theree = {
    "lat_long":"0.0,0.0",
    "name": "name 3"
};
```

---

If your key value is in a variable (let's called it a variable named `key`), then you use the `[key]` syntax:

```
var key = "theree";
data.participants[key] = {
    "lat_long":"0.0,0.0",
    "name": "name 3"
};
```

---

If what you really started with is an object like this:

```
var addData = {
    theree: {
        "lat_long":"0.0,0.0",
        "name": "name 3"
    }
}
```

where you don't know the value of `theree` and you need to get it from that object, then that's slightly more involved as you need to enumerate the properties of the `addData` object and add each one to the `participants` object:

```
// add all items from the addData object to the participants object
// this is essentially a merge of addData into participants
for (var prop in addData) {
    if (addData.hasOwnProperty(prop) {
        data.participants[prop] = addData[prop];
    }
}
```

---

Please note that though you used the terms `array` and `push` in your question, there is no array here and thus you don't use the `.push()` method.  You are simply adding properties to an object which can be added with a straight assignment to the new property name.

Also, please note that JSON is a text format designed for data interchange.  What you have here is a javascript object which is not the same as JSON.

Comment: Okay but what if i cant predict the `KEY` that is `three`

Comment: @NikhilM - I added that case to my answer also.  You would use this type of syntax: `data.participants[key]` where `key` is a variable with the property name in it.

Comment: `KEY` is dynamic i get it from some other proceess. I cant predict the value.

Comment: @NikhilM - yes, and my second code example allows you to have a variable with whatever dynamic value in it and use that variable without knowing its value ahead of time.  I show the assignment of a value to the `key` variable just for completeness in the example, but it can obtain its value however you want based on other code.  The point is that you have a variable with the property name in it and you use the `[varname]` syntax to access a dynamically named property.

Comment: @NikhilM - Since your question was a little unclear exactly which case you're asking about, I've added yet another possibility to my answer so there are now three different examples shown - the last two use dynamic key names.